# Salesforce CPQ: Contracted Pricing is Not Overriding Pricing Rule Price

Tags: apex, pricebook, cpq

If a product has only a list price and contracted pricing for the product and particular account is setup, whenever the user is adding that product to the Quote under that particular account, the contracted pricing is affecting. But this is not happening when the Product price is updating from Price Rule instead of List Price.

So, am confused with the cpq quote price order of execution.

Am I missing anything or it is a bug in Salesforce CPQ?.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few options here depending on the business need (just replying with one solution for now):

If the Contracted Price will always supersede the price rule(s):
 - Add a 'Price Condition':
[image: Price Condition for Price Rule]
 - This will ensure the Price Action will only fire if the 'Contracted Price' (API: SBQQ__ContractedPrice__c - Quote Line) is blank.

I'll stop there for now in case that resolves the issue but this is highly dependent on the complexity of the CPQ configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Yes indeed, if we have this condition, we can return the price from contracted pricing defined for the product and account. Actually, this suggestion will help me in one way. But what if a discount from contracted pricing should apply on top of price updated from price rule?.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, think it's probably best to understand the criteria for when this will apply e.g should the users have control over when to apply or are there business rules?

Comment: Hi Rob, Users do not have control over it. It is a business rule. For all the products we have price rule defined which will update/return the price for the product in the line editor. We also have discount applied on the contracted pricing for the particular account and product. So the business rule is to apply the discount on top of the price returned from the price rule.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue as well where we were trying to use contracted pricing to apply a % discount to products that had the "list price" set via a price rule instead of the pricebook entry.  I found in the SFDC help that it appears the contracted pricing logic only looks to the pricebook entry for the product.  Here is a like for more info on the SFDC help - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000isH7QAI 
There is an idea to fix this as well - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lOr2QAE